# How to migrate EC2 Snapshots to other EC2 account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have 2 Snapshots saved on my EC2 (Account 1), I created another AWS account (Account 2) and I want my 2 Snapshots from Account 1 to be present on my Account 2. In short I just want to migrate my 2 Snapshots from Account 1 to Account 2. Any way I can do this? Thanks!

**NOTES**

- Make sure that Account 1 and Account 2 are in the same `Zone`. Can be found in the top right of the the dashboard.
- From Snapshots page, change `Viewing` option to `Private Snapshots` (if the shared Snapshots is in Private mode).

Comment: that second point!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out Amazon [EBS Shared Snapshots](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2009/09/24/introducing-amazon-ebs-shared-snapshots/).

> Amazon EBS shared snapshots allows you to share these snapshots,
>   making it easy for you to share this data with your co-workers or
>   others in the AWS community. With this feature, users that you have
>   authorized can quickly use your Amazon EBS shared snapshots as the
>   basis for creating their own Amazon EBS volumes. If you choose, you
>   can also make your data available publicly to all AWS users. Users to
>   whom you have granted access can create their own EBS volumes based on
>   your snapshot; your original snapshot will remain intact. This is a
>   great way for developers to easily share data with the rest of the
>   Amazon EC2 community, and makes it easy for new customers to create
>   Amazon EBS volumes from an existing snapshot. For more information on
>   how to share snapshots refer to the Amazon EC2 User Guide’s EBS
>   section.

See this [blog post](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2009/09/shared-snapshots-for-ec2s-elastic-block-store-volumes.html) for more info.  This [blog post](http://shlomoswidler.com/2009/09/cool-things-you-can-do-with-shared-ebs.html) gives you a step-by-step, and some good use cases and warnings about sharing the snapshot.

Comment: I was able to share the Snapshots from Account 1, but I am stuck on how create a volume from Account 2 using the shared Snapshots from Account 1

Comment: "Once you have the sharee’s account number you, the sharer, go into the AWS Management Console and choose the Snapshots item. Find the snapshot you want to share and right-click on it, choosing “Snapshot Permissions”.



Fill in the sharee’s account number, without the separating dashes, into the dialog, and hit “Save”. It should only take a few seconds and… presto! The snapshot should be visible in the sharee’s AWS Management Console Snapshots page.

Comment: That's what I did, I removed the permission and share it again but still not available from sharee's Snapshots page. Also there's no confirmation/notification from Sharee's account that says about the shared Snapshots.

Comment: Is the `Availability Zone` an issue here? Account 1 and 2 zone are different. **EDIT**: Yeah its an issue! I saw it already.

Answer (score 5):

You can share a snapshot in one account so that it is visible in another account for creating EBS volumes, but there is no way to "migrate" or transfer EBS snapshot ownership completely from one account to another.

However you could follow this procedure:

1. In Account 1: Give Account 2 permission to create volumes from the EBS snapshot A (ModifySnapshotAttribute).
2. In Account 2: Create an EBS volume from the EBS snapshot A.
3. In Account 2: Create an EBS snapshot B from the EBS volume.
4. (Optional) In Account 2: Delete the EBS volume.
5. (Optional) In Account 1: Delete the EBS snapshot A.

This would result in an EBS snapshot B that is owned by Account 2 and is an exact copy of the EBS snapshot A in Account 1.

Comment: Interested as to why the down votes on this one. Eric's answer does what the question asks so can't see why its been marked as incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can make private amis.

Share the ami with another user

have them launch an instance

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-sharingamis.html#sharingamis-intro